# Convert text file to excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a text file with this format (the format is delimited by `---` and `||||` to make it look like a table)

[image: the format is delimited by --- and |||| to make it look like a table]

```
  st
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Server : hh site:          Date : 2012-03-10  Run Time :00.00.00
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AA       |dd                     |condition          |another                    |condition        |Ref.
yy       |sa33                   |true               |OK: 4tu                    |true             |yt.4.5
         |                       |                   |                           |                 |.3
---------|-----------------------|-------------------|---------------------------|-----------------|-----
BB       |tr  dd                 |2                  |dhfdk                      |                 |yt.5.1
         |verson                 |                   |    t3hd                   |    true         |.1
         |and above)             |                   |                           |                 |
---------|-----------------------|-------------------|---------------------------|-----------------|-----
```

**Content of the cell is all value. not heading. thanks**

I do not have any programming skills to read the file and parse it. How do I remove `----` and `|||||` and import in Excel as row and columns.

Comment: You will get better answers if you can upload the actual text in a code block.

Comment: Is the content of each cell the value or are there headings there too? You should explain the format in more detail and, as  tmthydvnprt suggests, provide the sample in a format that is easy to use, i.e. text.

Comment: Thank you for uploading text, will this work?

Comment: Hi tmthydvnprt, I need everything thats inside the cell in one column. thanks for your help.

Comment: See my update, it includes the top line.  You may have to play with it some more, but this should give you a start.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to using `Pandas` you could parse the file yourself and use a Python Excel library such as [`xlsxwriter`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/index.html) to create an `.xlsx` file:

```
from itertools import islice    
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook("output.xlsx")
ws = wb.add_worksheet()
cell_format = wb.add_format()
cell_format.set_text_wrap()
cell_format.set_align('top')

with open('input.txt', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='|')
    cells = []
    row_output = 1

    header = [row.strip() for row in islice(f_input, 0, 4)][2]
    ws.merge_range('A1:G1', header)
    #ws.write(0, 0, header)

    for row_input in csv_input:
        if row_input[0].startswith('---'):
            for col, cell in enumerate(zip(*cells)):
                ws.write(row_output, col, '\n'.join(cell), cell_format)
            row_output += 1
            cells = []
        else:
            cells.append(row_input)

wb.close()
```

This would create an Excel file in the same format as your data, i.e. each cell contains multiple lines:

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: Can it handle the top row?  This seems like a nice library, have not used it and I will have to put it in the back of my head in case I need it some time!

Comment: Yes, how do you need it though? In one cell or split somehow into columns?

Comment: I have updated the script do display the whole line as merged cells in the first row.

Answer (score 1):

The [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library should do everything need!

code in iPython environment:

```
import pandas as pd
from cStringIO import StringIO

text_file = '''
  st
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Server : hh site:          Date : 2012-03-10  Run Time :00.00.00
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AA       |dd                     |condition          |another                    |condition        |Ref.
yy       |sa33                   |true               |OK: 4tu                    |true             |yt.4.5
         |                       |                   |                           |                 |.3
---------|-----------------------|-------------------|---------------------------|-----------------|-----
BB       |tr  dd                 |2                  |dhfdk                      |                 |yt.5.1
         |verson                 |                   |    t3hd                   |    true         |.1
         |and above)             |                   |                           |                 |
---------|-----------------------|-------------------|---------------------------|-----------------|-----
'''

# Read in tabular data, skipping the first header rows
# StringIO(text_file) is for example only
# Normally, you would use pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', ...)
top = pd.read_table(StringIO(text_file), sep='\s{2,}', header=None, skiprows=3, nrows=1)
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(text_file), sep='|', header=None, skiprows=5)

# Remove '-' lines
df = df[~df[0].str.contains('-')]

# Reset the index
df = df.reset_index().drop('index', 1)

# Combine top line 
df = pd.concat([top, df], ignore_index=True)

df
```

---

[image]

---

Do whatever else you need to do to clean up the data, then write to excel:

```
# Write to excel file
df.to_excel('/path/to/file.xls')
```

Comment: Really? How exactly? This is no better than suggesting that the OP use Python.

Comment: OP needs to upload text first. I am not going to transcribe from image... But in general pandas will greatly help with this.

Comment: If you can not explain how to use pandas to process the file then this is not an answer. It could be a comment, but even that is not very helpful.

Comment: It *is* the answer.  Use pandas. Granted, it is not detailed. But I need the text.  Once it is uploaded I will add more details.

Comment: You shouldn't answer until you have all the information required.

Comment: sorry,but i need everything thats inside the cell in one column. like Condition true on the same line(column).

Comment: I wanted to entice the OP with a possible library so they would add more info.

Comment: @mhawke I hope I have shown pandas *is* the answer.  It is an **awesome** library that can be *very* powerful.

Comment: @noob keep in mind this is just to get you started, you will have to solve the specifics of you problem...

Comment: @tmthydvnprt:  You've shown that pandas is almost be the answer :) No argument there. There is still the issue that multi-line cells have been split into multiple rows. Can you show how to do that fix that?

Comment: haha @mhawke this is true. it is a little bit more of a stumper :)

Comment: technically, @noob did not make that a requirement.... I might leave that as an exercise for the OP ;)

Comment: Obviously it is a requirement. OP also says so in comment. C'mon show the power of pandas!

Comment: @tmthydvnprt. How do i make all the information in each cell in just one column. condition and true is in the same cell, I need it in the same column.

Comment: The only rationale I have is that SO is not a code writing service site... it is to answer questions in the general, pointing the asker in the right direction, which they must take further for their specific application.